# Предупреждение: work_time.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

В одном `layout` у меня много компонентов, вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И из за этого я получаю этот варнинг.

Поначалу я собирался это делать в `RecyclerView`, но потом подумал что все равно количество пунктов не увеличиться, то есть всегда будет равным 7 и каждый пункт и каждые компоненты написал вручную.

Вопрос:

Правильно ли делать так, или все таки правильнее использовать `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. В общем то это не проблема. Если тормозов на аппарате с установленным в проекте минимальным API нет, значит все хорошо. А вообще заведи дохлый девайс и тестируй на нем. Если все нормально, значит и на более новых аппаратах будет все хорошо.